# nodej cant load dataformat

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to run a node but i get this error, i tried updating the npm and tried to download the specific module. I also tried to change the js suffix to cjs as the error suggests nothing worked, any ideas
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5SNu.png

````
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1102
     throw new ERR_REQUIRE_ESM(filename, parentPath, packageJsonPath);
     ^

Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: /home/your-user/pool/node_modules/dateformat/lib/dateformat.js
require() of ES modules is not supported.
require() of /home/your-user/pool/node_modules/dateformat/lib/dateformat.js from /home/your-user/pool/lib/logger.js is an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which defines all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.
Instead rename dateformat.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use import(), or remove "type": "module" from /home/your-user/pool/node_modules/dateformat/package.json.

   at new NodeError (internal/errors.js:322:7)
   at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1102:13)
   at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
   at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
   at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
   at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:93:18)
   at Object.<anonymous> (/home/your-user/pool/lib/logger.js:11:18)
   at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
   at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
   at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32) {
 code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM' ```
````